# How to change Column Names of multiple csv file in R?

Tags: r

I have a five CSV file of data as shown below. It have first row "Category: All categories" and in the second row the column name Name and Marks.

```
Category: All categories    

Name Marks
Mohit 100
Raman 71
Kaveri 45
William 42
Ram Pravesh 37
```

I want to delete first row of the data so that it looks like this for all five files together.

```
Student Score
Mohit 100
Raman 71
Kaveri 45
William 42
Ram Pravesh 37
```

I am doing it manually, I believe there might be some short code to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can specify column names and how many lines to skip directly in `read.csv`.

For example below:

```
read.csv(file = "yourfile.csv",
         skip = 3, # How many lines you want to skip when you read it
         header = FALSE, # Skip the header too
         col.names = c("Student", "Score"), # Supply your own column names
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE
         )
```

For a full reproducible example:

```
# Generate data in text format
raw_file <-
  '
  Category: All categories    

Name, Marks
Mohit, 100
Raman, 71
Kaveri, 45
William, 42
Ram Pravesh, 37
'

# make a temp file to place data
temp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")

# write the temp file
writeLines(raw_file,con = temp_file)

read.csv(file = temp_file,
         skip = 4, # How many lines you want to skip when you read it
         header = FALSE, # Skip the header too
         col.names = c("Student", "Score"), # Supply your own column names
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

This will yield the following:

```
      Student Score
1       Mohit   100
2       Raman    71
3      Kaveri    45
4     William    42
5 Ram Pravesh    37
```

You also mentioned reading in multiple files:

```
# Get all the files that end in a csv in a given folder that you specify
files_to_read <- list.files(path = "some_path", pattern = ".csv", full.names = T)

# I like `purrr` here because it makes a few things easier
# Read in and row bind all csv to return a single data frame
library(purrr)
out <- map_dfr(files_to_read, ~read.csv(file = .x,
         skip = 4, # How many lines you want to skip when you read it
         header = FALSE, # Skip the header too
         col.names = c("Student", "Score"), # Supply your own column names
         stringsAsFactors = FALSE
))
```

Comment: how to save these files as separate file.... The above will merge all files in a single file .. I want the file to saved as multiple file.

Comment: Instead of `map_dfr` just  use `map`. That will return a list. If you want to save them out, then map(out, write.csv) @djM